# my code is below i want to change the icon of marker whose id match with <div> tag which is outside from map

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps

my code is below i want to change the icon of marker whose id match with  tag which is outside from map..

```
        var red_marker = "images/marker_red.png";
         function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 10,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.4, -1.897208)
            }
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
                    mapOptions);

            setMarkers(map, beaches);
        }
        var beaches = [
            ['ibis Birmingham Airport', 52.452656, -1.730548, 3, 'image2.jpg', 'image1.jpg', 'image3.jpg', '2000', 'Ambassador Road<br />Bickenhill<br />Solihull<br />Birmingham<br />B26 3AW', '(+44)1217805800', '(+44)1217805810', 'info@ibisbhamairport.com', 'http://www.booknowaddress.com'],
            ['ETAP Birmingham Airport', 52.452527, -1.731644, 2, 'image4.jpg', 'image5.jpg', 'image6.jpg', '2500', 'Ambassador Road<br />Bickenhill<br />Solihull<br />Birmingham<br />B26 3QL', '(+44)1217805858', '(+44)1217805860', 'info@etapbhamairport.com', 'http://www.booknowaddress.com'],
            ['ibis Birmingham City Centre', 52.475162, -1.897208, 1, 'image7.jpg', 'image8.jpg', 'image9.jpg', '3000', 'Ladywell Walk<br />Birmingham<br />B5 4ST', '(+44)1216226010', '(+44)1216226020', 'info@ibisbhamcity.com', 'http://www.booknowaddress.com']
        ];

        function setMarkers(map, locations) {

            var image = {
                url: 'images/marker_red.png'

            };
            var shape = {
                coords: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18, 1],
                type: 'poly'
            };
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;
            for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                var beach = locations[i];
                var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(beach[1], beach[2]);
              var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({maxWidth: 325}), marker, i;
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatLng,
                    icon: red_marker,
                    map: map
                });
                marker.set("type", "point");
                marker.set("id", beaches[i][3]);
                var mv = marker.get("id");


                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                    var imgs = beaches[i][4];
                    var contentString = '<div id="content">' +
                            '<div id="bodyContent">' +
                            '<div id="myCarousel5" class="carousel slide"><div class="carousel-           inner"><div class="item active"><div class="fill"><img class="col-md-12" src="listing_upload_images/'    +
                            beaches[i][4] + '"></div></div><div class="item"><div class="fill"><img class="col-md-12" src="listing_upload_images/' +
                            beaches[i][5] + '" ></div></div><div class="item"><div class="fill"><img class="col-md-12" src="listing_upload_images/' +
                            beaches[i][6] + '"></div></div></div><a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel5" data-slide="prev"><img src="images/left_arrow.png" class="arrow_position" ></a><a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel5" data-slide="next"><img src="images/right_arrow.png" class="arrow_position" ></a>' +
                            '</div><div class="money-info">' +
                            beaches[i][7] + '</div><div class="heart-img"><a href="#"></a></div><p><a href="#">'+
                            'In the Heart of Harlem, NYC</a></p><p><a class="gtrcvh" href="#">Private room  12 reviews  Harlem,</a></p>' +
                            '</div>' +
                            '</div>';

                    return function () {
                        infowindow.setContent(contentString);
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    }
                })(marker, i));


                $(".same-col-3").mouseover(function(){ 
                    if (mv == $(this).find("span").attr("id"))
                        {
                $("#2").mouseover(function () {
                    var icon = $(this).find("img").attr('src');
                    marker.setIcon(icon);
                });
                $("#2").mouseout(function () {
                    var icon = $(this).find("img").attr('alt');
                    marker.setIcon(icon);
                });
                }
                else{

                    return false;
                }
                 });
   });
            }
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

this is my code which open different infowindow data and I want to change the icon of marker which is change according to id whose id match with  from html

Comment: Can you specify the steps to get the effect you want? For example, 1) draw map with red_markers at beaches , 2) mouse clicks a red_marker on map , 3) popup opens and displays html , 4) ......

Comment: i want  only that marker shown with diffrent color on map whose id match with <div> tag "red marker become green" on mouser over the div

Answer (score 0):

You want to setup a listener on mouseover and mouseout events, instead of directly assigning the mouseover() and mouseout() function of the marker. Something like:

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function (marker, i) {
  return function () {
   console.log("hovering over item " + i);
   marker.setIcon(green_marker);
  };
 })(marker, i));

 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', (function (marker, i) {
  return function () {
   console.log("hovering over item " + i);
   marker.setIcon(red_marker);
  };
 })(marker, i));
```

Comment: Please visit this link

Comment: i want that single marker show when i mouseover on slider

Comment: i give the id to slider div "1", "2", "3", "4" i want that if i mouseover on slider 1st then first slider change the icon

Comment: here is html and id is given in <span> tag

Comment: @AakashSardana - Unfortunately you need to deal with the slider to make your icon change decisions since that is changing while you hover. You should ask another question on stackexchange to deal specifically with the carousel slider you're using in the popup. Good luck.